# inserting data in sqlite using batch operation in android

Tags: android, sqlite, bulkinsert

I'm getting records from web service using a retrofit. Getting records does not take much time but inserting in local db takes a few minutes. I tried inserting it using batch operation but I did not observe a big difference. Below is my web service response and db insertion method. Kindly check where I'm making mistake.

```
 private void getResponseAndInsert(){

    progressDialog = createProgressDialog(getActivity(), false);
    progressDialog.show();
    final ContentServiceCall request = ServiceGenerator.createService(ContentServiceCall.class, "Empty");
    final Call<VODServiceResponse> call = request.getAllVODCategories(Constants.WS_VERSION,Constants.LOCAL_EN,Constants.PLATFORM);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<VODServiceResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<VODServiceResponse> call, final Response<VODServiceResponse> response) {

            if(response!=null && response.isSuccessful())
            {
                if(response.body()!=null && response.body().getResponse()!=null)
                {
                    if(response.body().getResponse().getResponseCode()== Constants.RESPONSE_CODE_SUCCESS)
                    {
                        if(response.body().getVODCategories() != null)
                        {
                            VODCategories vodCategories;
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getVODCategories().size(); i++) {
                               //inserting in vod categories
                                vodCategories = response.body().getVODCategories().get(i);
                                dbHelper.insertVODCategories(vodCategories);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            // No data returned etc
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //response.body().getResponse().getMessage() display in toast
                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),response.body().getResponse().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    // leave it
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Display proper message
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<VODServiceResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Fail", "Failure");
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please Check your Internet Connection ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

db insertion method

```
    public boolean insertVODCategories(VODCategories vd) {

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(VODCATEGORIES_COLUMN_VODPARENTCATGORYID, vd.getVODParentCategoryId());
        initialValues.put(VODCATEGORIES_COLUMN_VODCATEGORYID, vd.getVODCategoryId());
        initialValues.put(VODCATEGORIES_COLUMN_VODCATEGORYNAME, vd.getVODCategoryName());
        initialValues.put(VODCATEGORIES_COLUMN_VODCATEGORYTHUMBNAILPATH, vd.getVODCategoryThumbnailPath());
        initialValues.put(VODCATEGORIES_COLUMN_VODCATEGORYIMAGEPATH, vd.getVODCategoryImagePath());
        initialValues.put(VODCATEGORIES_COLUMN_VODCATEGORYIMAGEPATHLARGE, vd.getVODCategoryImagePathLarge());
        initialValues.put(VODCATEGORIES_COLUMN_VODCATEGORYDESCRIPTION, vd.getVODCategoryDescription());
        initialValues.put(VODCATEGORIES_COLUMN_VODADDEDDATE, vd.getVODCategoryAddedDate());

        db.insert(TABLE_VODCATEGORIES, null, initialValues);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
        return true;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the batch operation wrong. You are doing a single insert in a db transaction which makes the transaction  useless. The point of a transaction is to do multiple operations.

You could do this:

```
List<VODCategories categories = response.body().getVODCategories();
List<ContentValues> valuesList = new ArrayList<>();
VODCategories vd;
for (int i = 0; i < categories.size(); i++) {
   vd = categories.get(i);
   ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(VODCATEGORIES_COLUMN_VODPARENTCATGORYID, vd.getVODParentCategoryId());
    initialValues.put(VODCATEGORIES_COLUMN_VODCATEGORYID, vd.getVODCategoryId());
    initialValues.put(VODCATEGORIES_COLUMN_VODCATEGORYNAME, vd.getVODCategoryName());
    initialValues.put(VODCATEGORIES_COLUMN_VODCATEGORYTHUMBNAILPATH, vd.getVODCategoryThumbnailPath());
    initialValues.put(VODCATEGORIES_COLUMN_VODCATEGORYIMAGEPATH, vd.getVODCategoryImagePath());
    initialValues.put(VODCATEGORIES_COLUMN_VODCATEGORYIMAGEPATHLARGE, vd.getVODCategoryImagePathLarge());
    initialValues.put(VODCATEGORIES_COLUMN_VODCATEGORYDESCRIPTION, vd.getVODCategoryDescription());
    initialValues.put(VODCATEGORIES_COLUMN_VODADDEDDATE, vd.getVODCategoryAddedDate());
    valuesList.add(initialValues);
}
dbHelper.insertVODCategories(valuesList);
```

Create a list of `ContentValues` for all objects and then

```
public boolean insertVODCategories(List<ContentValues> values) {

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            db.insert(TABLE_VODCATEGORIES, null, values.get(i));
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
        return true;

    }
}
```

insert all those values in a single transaction which should be faster.

Also `onResponse` is executed on the main thread. You might want to do the db operations on a background thread so you don't block the UI.